# Strange behaviour Angular driven select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

According to paper "How to set the initial selected value of a select element using Angular.JS ng-options & track by" by [@Meligy](https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/) which I used as a guidance to learn and solve my problem with implementing a select list (ng-options), I still encounter some strange collaterale behaviour.

Although the basic behaviour finally does what it should do, see [Test Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HShJT6NvRDL467ne8CwH?p=preview), I still encounter strange behaviour on the selected item in that list. Not in my test plunk though, implemented in my developement site.

```
app.controller("TaskEditCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.loadTaskEdit = loadTaskEdit;

  function loadTaskEdit() {
    taskLoadCompleted();
    tasktypesLoadCompleted();
  }

  function taskLoadCompleted() {
    $scope.tasks = [{
        Id: 1,
        Name: "Name",
        Description: "Description",
        TaskTypesId: 4
      }
    ];
    $scope.current_task_tasktypesid = $scope.tasks[0].TaskTypesId;    
  }

  function tasktypesLoadCompleted() {
    var tasktypes = [{ Id: 1, Name: "A" }, 
    { Id: 2, Name: "B" }, 
    { Id: 3, Name: "C" }, 
    { Id: 4, Name: "D" }];

    $scope.available_tasktypes_models = tasktypes    
  }

  $scope.submit = function(){
    alert('Edited TaskViewModel (New Selected TaskTypeId) > Ready for Update: ' + $scope.tasks[0].TaskTypesId);
  }

  loadTaskEdit();    
});
```

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate angular-validator name="editTaskForm" angular-validator-submit="UpdateTask()">        
        <div ng-repeat="task in tasks">             
          <div>
            <select ng-init="task.TaskTypes = {Id: task.TaskTypesId}" 
            ng-model="task.TaskTypes" 
            ng-change="task.TaskTypesId = task.TaskTypes.Id" 
            ng-options="option_tasttypes.Name for option_tasttypes in available_tasktypes_models track by option_tasttypes.Id">
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" ng-click="submit()" />
        </div>

      </form>
```

As said, see my test plunk which shows exactly what it supposed to do. Moreover, using 5 self-explaining images, I do hope to make my troulbe bit clearer what's the problem.

I'm a bit lost to figure out what's so troublesome. My 'water' is telling me something wrong or missing in css. Did have anybody out their ever have face comparable? What could cause me this trouble? Does have anybody out there have a clue?

Thanks in advance

[[image: Object Task does have a property TaskType][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3dSw.png)
[[image: Edit mode Object Task]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbD2v.png)
[[image: However no selected item visible, the correct list item seems to have focus]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCJOW.png)
[[image: Select item value is passed on (which in itself is correct)]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFfVs.png)

Apparently I'm a rookie on css. Any suggestion is welcome!

CSS
[image]

```
    #region "style sheets"
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
         "~/Content/css/site.css",
         "~/content/css/bootstrap.css",
         "~/content/css/bootstrap-theme.css",
         "~/Content/css/font-awesome.css",
         "~/Content/css/morris.css",
         "~/Content/css/toastr.css",
         "~/Content/css/jquery.fancybox.css",
         "~/Content/css/loading-bar.css"));
    #endregion "style sheets"
```

Comment: Can you add your CSS?

Comment: Can you please provide steps to reproduce a bug in your plunk?

Comment: Remove for example in line 28 the last 's' ng-model="task.TaskTypes" > ng-model="task.TaskType"  running the plunk again: three things, the list is filled (as expected) however no mapping with ng-init (line 27) isn't possible anymore, an empty item is added (preceding the list of items) and the 'to be mapped item' does receive the focus...

Comment: Running the test plunk without 'a mismatch': the list is filled as expected the correct item is selected as only item as wanted, and after clicking on de [V] the list is expanded and the selected item has received the focus (blue). In my development environment the expected item presented how after clicking [V] it did receive the focus... Strange!

Comment: Your model should be the selected item on the dropdown and not the list of taskTypes. So, try setting ng-model= current_task_tasktypesid. If you want to default the dropdown to be one of the options, set  $scope.current_task_tasktypesid = to the one that you want selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

The key with the dropdown is to set the model to the object that was selected. I updated your code to behave the way that I believe you are asking for it to work.

The key differences are:

1. Set the ng-model of the dropdown to the selected object and not the id of the selected item. This will give you access to the full selected object and all it's properties.
2. Remove the ng-change binding - this is not necessary with 2 way data binding, and the value on the model (whatever is put in for ng-model) will automatically be updated.
3. In your HTML you were using properties that were never declared in the Controller $scope. I updated those to reflect the available variables that were in scope.

For more information on dropdowns please see the angular documentation. It's very useful for figuring these types of issues out - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("TaskEditCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.tasks = {};
  $scope.current_task_tasktypesid = null;
  $scope.selected_task_tasktype = null;

  $scope.loadTaskEdit = loadTaskEdit;

  function loadTaskEdit() {
    taskLoadCompleted();
    tasktypesLoadCompleted();

    
    //EDIT: DEFAULT DROPDOWN SELECTED VALUE
    $scope.selected_task_tasktype = $scope.available_tasktypes_models[2];
  }

  function taskLoadCompleted() {
    $scope.tasks = [{
        Id: 1,
        Name: "Name",
        Description: "Description",
        TaskTypesId: 4
      }
    ];
    $scope.current_task_tasktypesid = $scope.tasks[0].TaskTypesId;

  }

  function tasktypesLoadCompleted() {
    var tasktypes = [{ Id: 1, Name: "A" }, 
    { Id: 2, Name: "B" }, 
    { Id: 3, Name: "C" }, 
    { Id: 4, Name: "D" }];
    
    $scope.available_tasktypes_models = tasktypes

  }
  
  $scope.submit = function(){
    alert('submitted model: ' + $scope.selected_task_tasktype.Id);
  }

  loadTaskEdit();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.9" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TaskEditCtrl as edit">

  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate angular-validator name="editTaskForm" angular-validator-submit="UpdateTask()">

    <div ng-repeat="task in available_tasktypes_models">
      
      <div>Task (Id): {{task.Id}}</div>
      <div>Name: {{task.Name}}</div>
      <div>Descripton: {{task.Description}}</div>
     </div>     
      <p>Current Task.TaskTypesId: {{selected_task_tasktype.Id}}</p>

      <div>
        <select
        ng-model="selected_task_tasktype" 
        ng-options="option_tasttypes.Name for option_tasttypes in available_tasktypes_models track by option_tasttypes.Id">
        </select>
      </div>
      <p>{{task.TaskTypes}}</p>
      <p>{{selected_task_tasktypesid = task.TaskTypes}}</p>
      
    

    <div class="">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" ng-click="submit()" />
    </div>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi dball, thanks for your comments. I try to achieve something more. I want to fill a selectlist not only with options but one option preselected! Understand: I do have the relation: Task<->TaskTypesId. This means TaskTypesId is a property of  a Task. On the EDIT/UPDATE dialog of a 'Task', I want to present a selectlist with the related TaskTypesId PRE-selected (simply because a task does have the property being a task of a certain task type) and offering the possibility to change this property. You get it? Please see my testplunker. At that stage it's working...

Comment: Please see @meligy's tutorial. In this paper he suggested a roadmap to follow. I pretty much followed his direction

Comment: Your comments are mainly about relics of the development procedure. I removed those in the plunk.

Comment: I updated the snippet. If you run it you can see that option C will be selected by default. You just have to set the value of ng-model to one of the values available from the source of your dropdown.

Comment: Hi, checking out your updated snippet, ha, ha (thanks for being with me)... isn't working. Initial you give it the Task.TaskTypesId = 3 >>> this will set option 'C' so far so good, however clicking on the [update] the alert is telling: Task.TaskTypesId = 4, moreover selecting another option always Task.TaskTypesId = 4 is passed on. So, this update isn't the way to go. Please, look at my plunk. This plunk (based on @meligy's stuff) is working as needed. My problem is however the core of my plunk implemented in my development environment shows weird behaviour as shown in the pictures.

Comment: Primarily not! Sorry about that... However, know that I do appreciate your input. In essence your input is not typically different what I have proposed with my plunk. Oke, you got rid of that ng-init and ng-change. Using those (as Meligy suggest) seems a bit 'hocus pocus' with Id's, however in return be aware of the fact to your solution needs a simple calculation to filter for the correct model... (Index of the list is not the Id of the model)...

Comment: Your solution did NOT solve the problem as initially described either. It does at 'Plunker' level... however not implemented in my development environment. Also your suggestion does NOT pre-set the TaskTypeId of the current Task in the select box, it does not show the current value as selected value, only after a click on the [V] the selectbox opens and the expected value shows it has received the focus, but it should be set as only selected item without having to click on [V]. This is what I have tried to explain in the first place (screen shots)...

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the behavior you are suggesting. I hope you are running the embedded snippet and not the plunker code, as I do not have permission to update....

I'm sorry that the only code posted was from the Plunker level and not from your development environment as you suggest. Perhaps you should post your development code in order for assistance in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

First, I need to state the implementation of @Meligy and the suggested input of 'dball' are correct. So, go with the flow of your choice.

Keep notice on your style sheets.

Finally, I figured out that the style property 'color' with the value 'white' of selector #editTaskWrapper as identifier of the parent

```
<div id="editTaskWrapper">
```

acted as the bad guy. One way or the other, if I comment 'color: white' in

```
#editTaskWrapper {
    background-color: #337AB7;
    /*color: white;*/
    padding: 20px;
}
```

the selected item in the selectlist becomes visible. All other controls and values are not affected, only the selected list item.